# Get Files form SFTP to Oracle

Tags: java

I want to read the files from a sftp directory, and then insert them in an Oracle table.
Because we don't have access on the server, we can't do that from Oracle.
So I thought about Java:
I found the following class:

https://atechblogagain.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/simple-sftp-example-in-java-with-jsch/
:

```
import java.util.Vector;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class DemoSftp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, SftpException {

        String hostname = "hostname";
        String login = "login";
        String password = "password";
        String directory = "the directory";

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        JSch ssh = new JSch();
        Session session = ssh.getSession(login, hostname, 22);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();

        ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        sftp.cd(directory);
        Vector files = sftp.ls("*");
        System.out.printf("Found %d files in dir %s%n", files.size(), directory);

        for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry file : files) {
            if (file.getAttrs().isDir()) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.printf("Reading file : %s%n", file.getFilename());
            BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sftp.get(file.getFilename())));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bis.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            bis.close();
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();

    }

}
```

It let me acces the SFTP directory and it prints the System.out.printf("Found %d files in dir %s%n", files.size(), directory) line, but it shows me an error at teh following line : for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry file : files) :

"Multiple markers at this line
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to 
     ChannelSftp.LsEntry
    - Line breakpoint:SFTPEX [line: 45] - main(String[])"

What do I have to change to make it work?
Can you help me with an example about how to white the file content into a column in a Oracle database? Each file has his own row, with name, type and content.

Comment: You have a Vector of Object class `Vector files`

Comment: I see that, I know that this is the error, but I'm verry new to Java, and I don't know what to do with what you told me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
 Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> files = sftp.ls("*");
```

You currently have a raw Object vector

Comment: It worked! It says about some exception handling for the reading part, but I resolved that. Can you help me/ give me a hint of how to write the file content in an Oracle table?